# How to correctly obtain SVG path data for Kinetic JS

Tags: canvas, svg, kineticjs

I'm using kinetic-v5.0.1 to place a graphic on a page (Eventually I want to do more..) but I'm having a problem getting it to render correctly.

I copied the example given at http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-path-tutorial/ but replaced the example path data with my own. To get the path data I exported a vector graphic from AI to SVG, then opened it in Sublime and pasted the path in.

Do I need to reformat the path data I got from my SVG, or do I need to export the SVG from a different application like CorelDraw/Inkscape etc.? I've tried putting spaces after the commas and changing the case of the M, C, L, Z etc. but nothing seems to work.

My path data:

```
data: 'M31.002,371.742 C10.851,335.694-0.64,294.146-0.64,249.912C-0.64,113.247,109,2.209,245.108-0.062l17.102,25.133l-17.102,25.155 C136.771,52.492,49.643,141.021,49.643,249.912c0,35.032,9.023,67.954,24.864,96.579l-29.783,0.744L31.002,371.742L31.002,371.742z',
```

Original path data:

```
data: 'M12.582,9.551C3.251,16.237,0.921,29.021,7.08,38.564l-2.36,1.689l4.893,2.262l4.893,2.262l-0.568-5.36l-0.567-5.359l-2.365,1.694c-4.657-7.375-2.83-17.185,4.352-22.33c7.451-5.338,17.817-3.625,23.156,3.824c5.337,7.449,3.625,17.813-3.821,23.152l2.857,3.988c9.617-6.893,11.827-20.277,4.935-29.896C35.591,4.87,22.204,2.658,12.582,9.551z',
```

Comment: I should add that when I use the original path data, the demo works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your curved arrow is being scaled off the stage.

```
// Try scaling at x:.2,y:.2 instead of x:2,y:2

scale: {x:.2, y:.2}
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9q7nD/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clue - I forgot to change the x and y position of the path on the stage! Now it's visible on the stage it looks correct. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks mark!  Thanks so much for helping out with SO questions.

Comment: @EricRowell Glad to help when I can...I like your KineticJS.  BTW, Kudos for the tutorial examples on your site. They nicely ease the learning curve for new KineticJS users.